# Error Object arrays are not currently supported Python

Tags: python, arrays

```
import numpy as np
import math

time_decay_parameter = 0.055
h_column1_formula = np.repeat(1, 10)
h_column2_formula = []
h_column3_formula = []
for maturity in range(1,10):
h_column2_formula.append( (1-math.exp(- 
time_decay_parameter*maturity))/(time_decay_parameter*maturity))
h_column3_formula.append(((1-math.exp(- 
time_decay_parameter*maturity))/(time_decay_parameter*maturity))- 
math.exp(-time_decay_parameter*maturity))



h_column2_formula_array = np.asarray(h_column2_formula)
h_column3_formula_array = np.asarray(h_column3_formula)

h_matrix = np.array([h_column1_formula,h_column2_formula_array,h_column3_formula_array]).T
print(h_matrix)
ht_h = h_matrix.T@h_matrix
```

The Error I get is the following

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-30a08b8e87fb> in <module>()
     17 print('HMATRIX \n')
     18 print(h_matrix)
---> 19 ht_h = h_matrix.T@h_matrix

TypeError: Object arrays are not currently supported
```

Comment: the h_matrix looks like this: [array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
 array([0.97299731, 0.94696241, 0.92185634, 0.89764183, 0.87428319,
       0.85174626, 0.82999835, 0.80900813, 0.78874564])
 array([0.02651216, 0.05112827, 0.07396263, 0.09512303, 0.11471107,
       0.13282253, 0.14954771, 0.16497171, 0.17917473])]

Comment: In h_matrix.T@h_matrix What will '@' do?

Comment: @mad_: That's the new-ish matrix multiplication operator.

Comment: does it differs from normal matrix multiplication in any sense?

Comment: the weird thing is if i change the for loop range to (1,31) it works... and in the output the h_matrix does not show the additional arrray(...) "thing", just the braces of each array

Comment: @mad_: That depends what you mean by "normal matrix multiplication". For numpy arrays, `A @ B` is equivalent to `np.dot(A, B)`. It's not the same as `A * B` since that does element-wise multiplication, rather than the fancier mathematical matrix multiplication.

Comment: @Con: Can you fix the indentation of the code? It's not obvious to me if the lines towards the bottom are inside the loop or not.

Comment: the for loop includes the, actually just two, lines just after the for declaration and before the 3 empty rows...

Comment: Please edit the question to fix it. You should probably include the output you put in a comment directly in the question too. Reading the comments shouldn't be necessary to understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that when you are trying to build your `h_matrix` array, it finds that it's rows don't all have the same length. The `h_column1_formula` array has length 10, the others are length 9.

So rather than building an array with a numeric `dtype`, it uses `dtype=object`, since that supports arbitrary contents (including arrays of different sizes). The matrix multiplication operator however complains about this, as it doesn't support object arrays, only numeric ones.

To fix this, you probably need to change some of the code you're using to build the matrix. Either your `range` call in the loop, or the `np.repeat` call should be changed so that the numbers line up properly.

I'd suggest either:

```
h_column1_formula = np.repeat(1, 9) # create an array with 9 values
```

or:

```
for maturity in range(1,11): # loop 10 times, 1-10
```